# Can I synchronize Plague Inc. mobile version with the PC version?

Tags: plague-inc

I watched some videos of Plague Inc (PC version) and I liked its graphics.  I started to play Plague Inc. on my mobile phone and I made some progress. After I saw the PC version's gameplay video, I decided to play it on PC.

Is there any way to synchronize my progress that I made on the mobile app with the PC version?

Comment: If you download an android emulator, such as Bluestacks or Koplayer, you can download and play the mobile version on a PC and use "Restore Progress" and "Restore Purchases". However, this is only the mobile version and you won't get features that actual PC useres would have.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This does not seem possible.

From what I understand, there are two versions of the game: **Plague Inc.** and **Plague Inc: Evolved**.  Plague Inc. is for mobile devices, while Plague Inc: Evolved is for PC/Mac.

From the [FAQS](http://www.ndemiccreations.com/en/29-plague-inc-evolved-faq) for Plague Inc: Evolved, question 4 asks:

> Is Plague Inc. Evolved different from Plague Inc. on mobile?

The answer:

> Yes – it is very different as we have been able to add a lot of things which would not work on mobile. Plague Inc: Evolved is a new game for PC, Mac and Linux which has been entirely redeveloped from the mobile game (Plague Inc.). It combines the original critically acclaimed gameplay of Plague Inc. with significant, all-new features...

Because of all the differences, there is no way to sync the two games.  Without [having support for cloud](http://steamcommunity.com/app/246620/discussions/0/558751364573599444/) saves either makes it more challenging for the developer to allow for syncing the two games.